# Ubuntu guest (running in VMware player) freezes on Windows Host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to run [Osboxes Ubuntu 20.4 guest image](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/#ubuntu-20-04-4-vmware) on Windows 10 Home 22H2 (both 64 bit) host using VMware Workstation 17 Player. My host configuration is Core i7 1065G7, 16GB RAM and 1TB NVMe SSD.

This is how my host configuration looks:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I use only Chrome browser on host (also not too many tabs). But even with that use my Ubuntu freezes. I cannot even shutdown the Ubuntu. Why is that?

Comment: I think this is a bug in VMware V17.  I have the same thing in Workstation V17.  No VMware notes just yet, and there may be an update soon

Comment: This doesnt happen in VMware Player v16? Also across any link where people are discussing the same? I just found [this thread](https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLScw0JPJ5inPH27za3CnzM1fHHh3h9Vh9oFf1hzVn36gWRD53w/formResponse?pli=1) opened five days ago, but its says its moved to another forum. Cant find it.

Comment: Yes. VMware V16 is fine. But there are no fixes for V17.   Uninstall Player, restart the host and install Player again.  I am doing this for Workstation. A clean install of Player may fix the issue.

Comment: You mean reinstalling V17 itself will work? Or suggesting to install V16? (Because my V17 installation is just a week old!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freezing issue does appear to be a bug in VMware version 17.

I suggest you do a full uninstall of VMware Player V17.

Restart the host computer.

Now install VMware Player V16.

Stay with V16 for a month or two - it works fine.

Then try V17 after some updates have returned.

You can try V17 again right away, but there is no guarantee that will fix the freezing issue.

**So for stability, return to VMware Player V16 for a month or two.**

Comment: It has been a year and I see this problem. Lucky your post saves my date. I now use V16. If V16 works, I may not update to V17. VMware needs to work on this issue.

Comment: It's now almost 2 years since the issue started happening... even with the latest VMware workstation update, the bug persists...

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an issue in the keyboard related driver in VMware 16/17, try adding the following lines to the bottom of the .vmx file, it helps in my case.

```
keyboard.allowBothIRQs = "FALSE"
keyboard.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

- Create a blank VM and install Ubuntu from an ISO. I always do it like that.
- Check if virtualization is enabled in your hosts BIOS.
- Reduce VM processor count to 2 and RAM to 4GB.
- Use VirtualBox instead of VMWare Player
- Try a different browser. It might be a problem with Chrome.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows, with heavy load the VM freezes. I changed the cpu affinity, on an Intel i5-1235U, 2P+8E, and moved the guests from the P-cores to only all E-cores. Later I added just 1 P-core per guest. Looks good for now...